# Cannot Zoom UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I am new to swift.

I am doing an exercise from an app development book. I am trying to create an `UIImageView` and put a image in it, but I can not zoom the image in. There is something wrong in my code, but I don't know what is going on.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scroll.delegate = ViewController()
        updateZoomFor(size:view.bounds.size)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    private func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIImageView{
        return image
    }

    func updateZoomFor(size:CGSize){
        let widthScale = size.width / image.bounds.width
        let heightScale = size.height / image.bounds.height
        let scale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        scroll.minimumZoomScale = scale
    }

}
```

Comment: Check isUserInteractionEnabled property is true or not for UIImageView

Comment: Instead of `scroll.delegate = ViewController()` try `scroll.delegate = self`

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/159481/uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set `scroll.delegate = self` as suggested by 3stud1ant3.

Second, you need to match the definition of the`UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
  return image
}
```

Make sure you set the zoom scale in `updateZoomFor` as well: `scroll.zoomScale = scale`.

Also you need to implement this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {  
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
  updateZoomFor(size: view.bounds.size)
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  updateConstraintsForSize(view.bounds.size)
}

fileprivate func updateConstraintsForSize(_ size: CGSize) {

  let yOffset = max(0, (size.height - imageView.frame.height) / 2)
  imageViewTopConstraint.constant = yOffset
  imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = yOffset

  let xOffset = max(0, (size.width - imageView.frame.width) / 2)
  imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xOffset
  imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = xOffset

  view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: there is an error of last line. so i need to define updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size) first? Also i have run the script without the last line. when i enlarge the image in simulator, it will return back to original size of the image. It is normal situation?

Comment: ok. I have edited the answer to use your `updateZoomFor` function instead. Try it again, and make sure to connect the constraints as `IBOutlet`s.

Comment: i have some problem of the imageViewLeadingConstraint, TrailingConstraint,BottomConstraint and TopConstraint when i run the simulator. Do i need to define them first?

Comment: Yes. So add constraints in Interface builder first. Then ctrl-drag each constraint to your view controller to add them as outlets with the same names I have provided above.